# No Activity found to handle Intent, when starting Google Maps

Tags: android, android-intent

This works fine, to start Google Play Music (although weirdly it gives me a choice of "Play Music" or "Google Play Music"):

```
            Intent musicIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            musicIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.music");
            musicIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(musicIntent);
```

The same thing for Google Maps doesn't work. This:

```
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            mapIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Gives:

```
Unhandled exception in callback
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.google.android.apps.maps }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:663)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:645)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:331)
```

I've double checked the package name. I can only guess that isn't the string I'm supposed to be using. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is  google maps installed on that device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> although weirdly it gives me a choice of "Play Music" or "Google Play Music"

An app is welcome to have multiple `ACTION_MAIN` activities. For example, it might have multiple launcher activities, or it might have a dedicated launcher activity for Android TV to go along with a standard launcher activity.

> What am I doing wrong?

You mean, besides assuming that the user has Google Maps installed, has Google maps enabled, and wants to use Google Maps, versus using some other map application?

You are looking for `ACTION_MAIN`, `CATEGORY_DEFAULT`, in `com.google.android.apps.maps`. There is no requirement for any app to have `ACTION_MAIN` for `CATEGORY_DEFAULT`.

Your choice of `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` is implied by creating an `Intent`, not associating it with any category, and using it with `startActivity()`. You might wish to use `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`. Or, [use `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Ah I see. Yes obviously I haven't finished developing my app yet - I don't think I said that this is production code.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt go same with maps.

From the Google Maps Documentation, they say,

> All Google Maps intents are called as a View action — ACTION_VIEW.

Try the below way:

```
showMap(Uri.parse("geo:47.6,-122.3"););

public void showMap(Uri geoLocation) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(geoLocation);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else{
        // No application is available that can handle this intent
    }
}
```

Please check the documentation of [Common Intents for Maps](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps)

Also, Intent requests Section in [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents)

Answer (score 1):

Change  `ACTION_MAIN` with `ACTION_VIEW`

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
mapIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```